# How to enable SQL authentication using SqlIaasExtension extension

Tags: sql-server, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to configure the SqlIaasExtension extension to post configure a SQL Server VM to use SQL Authentication while also specifying the sqlUser and sqlPassword.  The deployment of the extension succeeds, but the SQL Authentication method is never enabled.  I can't seem to find resource manager documentation that might help tell me what I'm missing.  It also seems that another person had a similar issue, but the problem resolved itself (mine didn't).

[How to enable SQL Authentication with ARM Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156924/how-to-enable-sql-authentication-with-arm-template)

```
{
          "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
          "type": "extensions",
          "name": "SqlIaasExtension",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "condition": "[parameters('deployVMs')]",
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "SQLIaas VM Extension"
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('vm-ssis-', parameters('environment.prefix'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "type": "SqlIaaSAgent",
            "publisher": "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "1.2",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": "true",
            "settings": {
              "AutoTelemetrySettings": {
                "Region": "[resourceGroup().location]"
              },
              "AutoPatchingSettings": {
                "PatchCategory": "WindowsMandatoryUpdates",
                "Enable": true,
                "DayOfWeek": "Sunday",
                "MaintenanceWindowStartingHour": "0",
                "MaintenanceWindowDuration": "240"
              },
              "ServerConfigurationsManagementSettings": {
                "SQLConnectivityUpdateSettings": {
                  "ConnectivityType": "Private",
                  "Port": "1433",
                  "SQLAuthUpdateUserName": "[parameters('admin.username')]",
                  "SQLAuthUpdatePassword": "[parameters('admin.password')]"
                },
                "SQLWorkloadTypeUpdateSettings": {
                  "SQLWorkloadType": "General"
                },
                "AdditionalFeaturesServerConfigurations": {
                  "IsRServicesEnabled": "false"
                }
              },
              "protectedSettings": {
                "SQLAuthUpdateUserName": "[parameters('admin.username')]",
                "SQLAuthUpdatePassword": "[parameters('admin.password')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Is there an error message ?

Comment: No error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this same issue because I was putting the "protectedSettings" section in the wrong place. The "protectedSettings" section is a sibling of the "settings" section, not a child.

```
{
   ...
   "properties": {
       ...
       "settings": {
           ...
       },
       "protectedSettings": {
           "SQLAuthUpdateUserName": "[parameters('admin.username')]",
           "SQLAuthUpdatePassword": "[parameters('admin.password')]"
       }
   }
}
```